# case sensitivity affects SQL parsing in oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, parsing, query-optimization

I know

```
select * from employees;
```

and

```
select * from Employees;
```

will generate 2 diff SQLids and hash value but eventually use same hashplan value.
So it this soft parse or hard parse? 
and will both statements will use same execution plan if plan hashvalue is same?

Answer (score 2):

They are different cursors, so yes the second one will require a full parse and optimisation.

The optimiser will evaluate each one separately, but since they are really the same query (same tables, some joins, filters etc) then it will produce the same execution plan unless something changes between parsing the first and the second query.

Note this is one advantage of PL/SQL, since the compiler internally strips all formatting and case differences, which means that if they are used in PL/SQL they will become the same cursor.

Comment: "It will produce the same execution plan" - this means hard parse?
In shared pool we will have 2 execution plan with same hash_plan_number.?
if not then 2nd statement should be soft parsed?

Comment: Yes, hard parse. Plans are stored with the cursor. There is no caching benefit as far as I know if a different cursor happens to use the same plan.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these two statements will get a different `sql_id`. However, as you can see in **[the following demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3b38d40213b1d1dfae0ba279e7db6279)**, the `plan_hash_value` of the two statements remains the same.

Since the `plan_hash_value` uniquely identifies a hard parse and the related execution plan, this indicates that the optimizer does figure out that both queries as identical, and retrieves the existing plan in the shared pool instead of hard parsing a second time.

```
create table employees(id int);

select * from employees;

| ID |
| -: |

select sql_id, hash_value, plan_hash_value
from v$sql 
where sql_text like 'select * from %mployees';

SQL_ID        | HASH_VALUE | PLAN_HASH_VALUE
:------------ | ---------: | --------------:
f34thrbt8rjt5 | 4069246757 |      1445457117


select * from Employees;

| ID |
| -: |

select sql_id, hash_value, plan_hash_value
from v$sql 
where sql_text like 'select * from %mployees';

SQL_ID        | HASH_VALUE | PLAN_HASH_VALUE
:------------ | ---------: | --------------:
f34thrbt8rjt5 | 4069246757 |      1445457117
bvgw7mnuubskb |  900063819 |      1445457117
```

**[Here](https://www.orskl.com/new-sql_id-does-not-mean-hard-parsing-or-new-execution-plan-3/)** is a related reading.

Comment: [cursor sharing](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_cursor.htm#TGSQL-GUID-7A37EEAC-1B50-4744-B4BC-A3052313A7E4)
In cursor sharing:
The text of the statement is hashed.
if the SQL statement does not currently exist in the shared pool, so the database performs a hard parse. This ends the shared pool check.
In above demo it should have done hard parse?
Also both these statements will have different parent cursors?